# How to select last element of a particular class

Tags: javascript

I was wondering why foo is logging a value while bar isn't.  They seem to be syntactically identical too.

EDIT: This was an X-Y problem. My aim is to get the last element with the class `foo` and I tried to get this using `last-child`. I tried `last-of-type` to no avail.

```js
const foo = document.querySelector(".some-element:last-child")
const bar = document.querySelector(".foo:last-child")

console.log('foo >>',foo)
console.log('bar >>',bar)
```

```html
<article>
  <div class="foo">This `div` is first.</div>
  <div class="foo">This <span>nested `span` is last</span>!</div>
  <div>This <em>nested `em` is first</em>, but this <em>nested `em` is last</em>!</div>
</article>
<ul>
  <li class="some-element">1</li>
  <li class="some-element">2</li>
  <li class="some-element">3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: why is this a surprise? None of the `.foo` elements are the last child of their parent.

Comment: Which `.foo` is the last child of its parent?

Comment: I see. I suppose my aim is completely different. How would I select the last element with class `foo`?

Comment: I don't think you can do that with CSS selectors. You'd need some sort of "look-ahead" in the DOM tree, which selectors don't provide.

Comment: XPath could do this, but XPath sucks at selecting elements by class. Sigh.

Comment: @reactor Sometimes an alternative is to put your last-element styles in a `.foo` rule, then undo them in a `.foo ~ .foo` rule (`.foo ~ .foo` being equivalent to `:not(:last-of-class(.foo))` if the `:last-of-class(.foo)` selector you were looking for existed).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `querySelectorAll()` for select all element by class.

and for get the last element with class try this:

```
const bar = document.querySelectorAll(".foo")
console.log( 'bar >>', bar[bar.length - 1] )
```

Take a look at the [Selectors Overview](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#overview)

Comment: I reckon this means that there is no pseudo-selector based way to grab this?